# asio timer from other class

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

I try this : [timer tuto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).
But the void print is in another class. When i call the function in main:

```
t.async_wait(&class::print);
```

I have this error :

> `error : must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'boost::asio::detail::lvref<void (class::*)(const boost::system::error_code&)>() (...)', e.g. '(... ->* boost::asio::detail::lvref<void (class::*)(const boost::system::error_code&)>())`

I don't know how fix this issue :s

> You will have to bind the object instance, like: t.async_wait(boost::bind(&Class::print, this, _1)); Or if the instance is not this, use another (smart) pointer that points to a Class. You can use a reference, but that requires a reference wrapper to prevent bind from copying the bound argument: Class c;
>   // ...
>   t.async_wait(boost::bind(&Class::print, boost::ref(c), _1));

I have already tried, but I have an error :

```
error : 'void (class::*)(const boost::system::error_code&)' is not a class, struct, or union type typedef typename F::result_type type;
```

> You need to handle the parameter that the print method expects.
>   Something like this:
>   t->async_wait(boost::bind(&Class::print, this,
>         boost::asio::placeholders::error));
>   Take a look at this tutorial http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html

I try but I have an error which i don't understand

```
error : pointer to member type 'void (class::)(const boost::system::error_code&)' incompatible with object type 'windows'
     BOOST_MEM_FN_RETURN (get_pointer(u)->*f_)(b1);
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the object instance, like:

```
t.async_wait(boost::bind(&Class::print, this, _1));
```

Or if the instance is not `this`, use another (smart) pointer that points to  a `Class`. You *can* use a reference, but that requires a reference wrapper to prevent bind from copying the bound argument:

```
Class c;

// ...
t.async_wait(boost::bind(&Class::print, boost::ref(c), _1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the parameter that the print method expects.

Something like this:

```
t->async_wait(boost::bind(&Class::print, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Take a look at this tutorial  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html